# Pi 2 Windows IoT support for onboard CSI camera port

Tags: pi-2, camera, raspicam, windows-iot

I am working on IoT technology, in one of my project I want to connect to on-board camera with Raspberry Pi 2 having Windows 10 IoT core.

Two months back I found Windows IoT on the Raspberry Pi 2 didn't support the on-board camera.

Has this changed?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. The Foundation aren't involved in Windows support on the Pi, that's entirely Microsoft's bailiwick, and so far I haven't heard anything from Microsoft regarding camera support. There was a ticket regarding [picamera support on Win10 IoT](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/issues/222) but I've heard nothing further since then.

Comment: For any future readers, as of April 2017 there is still no support for CSI drivers nor any mention of it by Microsoft. This question is on the front page of my Google queries.

Comment: It seems that there is no support for CSI drivers in 2019.